# Uploading multiple files through Django formset - MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: python, django, file, upload, formset

Trying to make an app which handles multiple file uploads and stores them to a standard location, but i've encountered a problem. When submitting the form, django returns "MultiValueDictKeyError at /pdfchecker/

"'docfile'" "

forms.py

```
    from django import forms

class UploadPdf(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='Browse')

class UploadPdfUrl(forms.Form):
    docurl = forms.URLField(label='Address')
```

modelys.py

```
    from django.db import models

class handle_UploadPdf(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='.')
```

views.py

def upload(request):

```
UploadPdfFormSet = formset_factory(UploadPdf, max_num=10,)


if request.method == 'POST':
    formsetFile = UploadPdfFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if formsetFile.is_valid():
        newdoc = handle_UploadPdf(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
        newdoc.save()

        return HttpResponse('yey')
else:
    formsetFile = UploadPdfFormSet()
    formURL = UploadPdfUrl

return render(request, 'pdfchecker/index.html', {
    'formsetFile': formsetFile, 'formURL': formURL,
    })

page_visits = int(request.COOKIES.get('page_visits', '0'))

if request.COOKIES.has_key('last_visit'):

    last_visit = request.COOKIES['last_visit']

    last_visit_time = datetime.strptime(last_visit[:-7], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    if (datetime.now() - last_visit_time).seconds > 5:

        response.set_cookie('page_visits', visits+1)

        response.set_cookie('last_visit', datetime.now())
else:

    response.set_cookie('last_visit', datetime.now())

return response
```

HTML template:

```
<div class="f_unify">
        <form class="simpleform" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ formsetFile.management_form }}
            {% for form in formsetFile.forms %}
                        <fieldset class="mainfieldset">
                        <legend class="outer">
                        <span class="legendtext">Check by URI</span>

                        </legend>
                        <div class="singlerow">

                        {% csrf_token %}
            {{ formURL.as_table }} 

                        <input type="submit" value="Check" />
                        </div>


            <span class="description">(<cite>http://www.egovmon.no/test.pdf</cite>)</span>
                        </fieldset>


            {% endfor %}
        </form>
                <form class="simpleform" action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ formsetFile.management_form }}
            {% for form in formsetFile.forms %}
                        <fieldset class="mainfieldset">
                        <legend class="outer">
                        <span class="legendtext">Check by File Upload</span>
                        </legend>

                        <div class="singlerow">
            <div class="table">
                <input type="submit" value="Check" />
            <table class='no_error'>        
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ formsetFile.as_p }}

            </table>

                        </div>

            </div>



                        </fieldset>
            {% endfor %}
            <script>
                var maxRows = 10;
                var i = 1;
                $('#add_more').click(function() {
                    if(i < maxRows) {
                    cloneMore('div.table:last', 'service' + i++);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('You can only upload 10 files per instance')
                        }
                })

            </script>


        </form>


</div>
```

Settings.py:

```
    """
Django settings for testproject project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '0o0g&$q4jeg%d#+5gu^b2x0jclifrul-3^q0e9(x_vwqdz3+x@'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pdfchecker',
    'authentication',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testproject.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS =(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static"),
    )
```

Error:

```
Error:

    MultiValueDictKeyError at /pdfchecker/

"'docfile'"

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://tt5.s.tingtun.no:7842/pdfchecker/
Django Version:     1.6.1
Exception Type:     MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    

"'docfile'"

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 301
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/student/django/1utkast/src',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TingtunUtils-0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-2.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']

Server time:    Mon, 28 Apr 2014 14:10:07 +0000
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response

                        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/student/django/1utkast/src/pdfchecker/views.py in upload

                newdoc = handle_UploadPdf(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__

                raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

    ...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: R u having the issue still

Comment: @rajasimon nope. I fixed it. Can't remember how though. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

In views.py,

```
request.FILES['docfile']
```

raises the MultiValueDictKeyError, where

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    formsetFile = UploadPdfFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if formsetFile.is_valid():
        newdoc = handle_UploadPdf(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
        newdoc.save()

        return HttpResponse('yey')
```

This code snippet don't check if requested files hold the file 'docfile' and so it gives the multivaluedictkeyerror. So if you check whether 'docfile' is in the request.FILES previously then it solves the error.

```
if formsetFile.is_valid() and 'docfile' in request.FILES:
    newdoc = handle_UploadPdf(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
    newdoc.save()
```

Because request.FILES['docfile'] don't compile if it's not located in request.FILES

Comment: Please add some descriptions to your code answers

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks a lot for providing me the resources.